# SQL-Server - Select sequentially into groups then start over but keep grouped id's together

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to assign a value to each row sequentially up to a number, let's say 7, then start over at 1. The only catch is that if the id's are the same for two rows they need to stay together.

The first two columns are my data and the third is what I'd like to assign:

| Individual_ID | Site_ID | Code_Assignment |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0001 | 0070000036 | 1 |
| 0001 | 0090000028 | 2 |
| 0001 | 0100000002 | 3 |
| 0002 | 0100000002 | 3 |
| 0001 | 0100000004 | 5 |
| 0001 | 0100000009 | 6 |
| 0002 | 0100000009 | 6 |
| 0003 | 0100000009 | 6 |
| 0001 | 0100000029 | 7 |
| 0002 | 0100000029 | 7 |
| 0003 | 0100000029 | 7 |
| 0001 | 0100000030 | 1 |
| 0002 | 0100000030 | 1 |
| 0001 | 0100000032 | 2 |
| 0002 | 0100000032 | 2 |
| 0003 | 0100000032 | 2 |
| 0001 | 0100000033 | 3 |
| 0001 | 0100000036 | 4 |
| 0002 | 0100000036 | 4 |
| 0001 | 0100000040 | 5 |
| 0002 | 0100000040 | 5 |
| 0001 | 0100000044 | 6 |
| 0002 | 0100000044 | 6 |
| 0001 | 0100000045 | 7 |
| 0002 | 0100000045 | 7 |
| 0001 | 0100000046 | 1 |
| 0002 | 0100000046 | 1 |

Comment: There isn't enough information here. What is the logic for assigning these numbers? Your output seems to be relying on some sort of ordering but there is nothing in your data to indicate the order of the rows.

Comment: No logic needed just splitting them into groups as they are read from the table sequentially.

Comment: By definition a table is an unordered set. You can't just "read them sequentially". But looking at your data maybe the ordering predicates might be Site_ID, Individual_ID?

Comment: Why do the rows with `0100000009` are considered equal, but rows with `0100000002` are different?

Comment: Sorry guys made a mistake on the sample data. You are correct they should be the same. Also yes unordered really is fine although keeping the id's together I assume would need to be ordered by the id fields.

Comment: The point is you MUST have something to use for ordering or you can't be sure the values will be correct. You can't "keep the id's together" if you have nothing to order them by.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `DENSE_RANK()` to compute the number. For example:

```
select t.*,
  (dense_rank() over(order by site_id) - 1) % 7 + 1 as code_assignement
from t
```

Result:

```
 id  site_id     code_assignement 
 --- ----------- ---------------- 
 1   0070000036  1                
 1   0090000028  2                
 1   0100000002  3                
 2   0100000002  3                
 1   0100000004  4                
 1   0100000009  5                
 2   0100000009  5                
 3   0100000009  5                
 1   0100000029  6                
 2   0100000029  6                
 3   0100000029  6                
 1   0100000030  7                
 2   0100000030  7                
 1   0100000032  1                
 2   0100000032  1                
 3   0100000032  1
```

It seems your example is not correct for rows with value `0100000002`; they should produce the same code, not different ones.

See example at [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=5596ec70ccc48300662a502405505f74).

Comment: Yes my mistake on the sample data. Fought the post trying to get it formatted correctly. Thanks for the response this looks like it will give me what I'm looking for.